# How to Access app.properties in tapestry 5 tml files

Tags: tapestry

Accessing index.properties name-value is easy in a tml, one simply uses ${message.greeting} in index.tml

```
<h1>${message:greeting}</h1>
```

How does one access a name-value called welcome from the app's general app.properties file in index.tml?

Answer (score 1):

It's done exactly the same way. Tapestry first looks in the page's property file, if any, and then in app.properties.

<h1>${message:welcome}</h1>

See https://tapestry.apache.org/localization.html